# text-mine PDF files with Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text-mining

Is there a package/library for python that would allow me to open a PDF, and search the text for certain words?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [PyPdf2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/) you can use [extractText()](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465/) method to extract pdf text and work on it.

Update: Changed text to refer to PyPdf2, thanks to @Aditya Kumar for heads up.

Comment: @cartman: do you have any idea how to work with the fact that PyPdf does not put a space between lines? For example, if one line in the pdf said 'hello' and then the next line said 'world' the text i extract out is 'helloworld' instead of 'hello world' which kind of kills any text mining...

Comment: If I remember correctly, PyPdf reads some newlines in some PDFs as '\x00'.

Comment: +1 for pyPdf: It's a _very_ handy module, even if a bit outdated for 2.6 (the sources are available anyway, it's but a few adaptations).

Comment: The original pypdf project is no longer maintained. However, there is pypdf2 now: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do it in one step, but you can certainly get the text out of a pdf with [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html). Then you can apply whatever text search to that recovered data.